# How to capture errors inside trigger

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, error-handling, triggers

I want to create trigger which should capture all error whatever it happens inside the trigger.
And it should store in some log table.
Here my challange is `how to capture the error occur in DML statments`.
THat DML statments error captured in log with `respective table name along with column name and error message`.
It should also caputre all other errors like no_data_found with exact line number.

Please look at my code below.
If any changes need tell us.

```
create or replace TRIGGER user_name.sample_trg 
AFTER UPDATE ON user_name.transaction_tb
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
 variable_ln  number;
 l_err   varcha2(4000);
  
BEGIN
    select column_value
    into variable_ln
    from tb1
    where colum_1 = :NEW.colum_1
    

    IF UPDATING THEN

      INSERT
      INTO hisotry_tb
        (
          column1,
          column2,
          column3,
          column4,
        )
        VALUES
        (
          :NEW.column1,
          :NEW.column2,
          :NEW.column3,
          :NEW.column4,
        );
        
     END IF; 

IF INSERTING THEN

      INSERT
      INTO hisotry_tb
        (
          column5,
          column6,
          column7,
          column8,
        )
        VALUES
        (
          :NEW.column5,
          :NEW.column6,
          :NEW.column7,
          :NEW.column8,
        );
        
     END IF;     
        
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    l_err := DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK || DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE;
    INSERT INTO log (erro_msg, trigger_name, column_name) 
    VALUES (l_err, 'sample_trg', '?');
    
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_err);
  
END;
```

Comment: Oracle `INSERT` has an error logging clause you could add to the `INSERT` statements.  Here is a link to the documentation ([Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423__BGBDIGAH))

Comment: Insert into logging tables should be performed inside another procedure with `pragma autonomous_transaction`, because error logging should not break current transaction. With current code you will not log anything in case of rollback

Comment: Triggers should not have exception handler that does not terminate in `RAISE` The exception rejects this row  (no insert, no update) but to the issuer of the DML it looks just like a completed action. If the caller subsequently `commits` this particular row has not been processed. Suppose the transaction was a money transfer and this was the row that added to your account. Now the funds would be successfully taken form the sender account but not added to yours. Try resolving that mess. That is why there should not even be a trigger write history belongs in the app with the actual DML.

Comment: As a frame challenge, why do you think an error would be associated with a particular table and column?  An error might be that a check constraint is violated that involves several columns.  An error might be that the user's quota on whatever tablespace the table is using has been exceeded.  It doesn't make a huge amount of sense to tie that to the table though I guess you could but you can't tie it to a column.  An error might be that there is a trigger on `history_tb` that failed validation.

Comment: BTW: Ccurrently there is no need to check for 'If UPADTING` or `If INSERTING`. As written the trigger only fires on npdate not insert. That is what `AFTER UPDATE` specifies.

Comment: @astentx If i develope procedure to capture error in log table, how can i get input for that procedure to load data inside log table. I mean there may be DML statement increases in future.

Comment: @Del Error logging clause will not work for common log table that we create right?

Comment: @JustinCave I cant able to understand what u mentioned. I want to store whatever error occured inside the trigger should be captured in log table including DML error too. Is this possible.?

Comment: You can get the error message.  You can get the line number.  The error may or may not be associated with one or more tables.  It may or may not be associated with one or more columns in that table.  If we restrict ourselves to just constraint violation errors, you could in theory parse the error message looking for a constraint name and then use that constraint name to determine which table and column to use in your log table.  But that is likely to be rather fragile code and it won't handle every error that could possibly be thrown.

Comment: It would almost certainly make more sense to just log the error code/ error message/ call stack/ error stack/ etc.